# Rails Nested Singular Resource Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing, nested-resources

I have a simple User model with a singular nested Profile resource so in my routes.rb I have:

```
resources :users do
  resource :profile, :only => [:edit, :update, :show]
end
```

This generates the expected routes:

```
edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles"}
     user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}
     user_profile PUT    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"profiles"}
```

I've created a simple controller update method that updates the model and then redirects upon successful update:

```
def update
  @profile = Profile.find_by_user_id(params[:user_id])
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
      format.html { redirect_to( user_profile_path(@user, @profile), :notice => 'Profile was successfully updated.') }
    else
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that once the form is submitted, the form redirects to mydomain.com/users/4/profile.22 where 22 happens to be the id of the profile.  Clearly this confuses the controllers since the routing interprets the '22' as the format.

My question is, **how do I get this to redirect to mydomain.com/users/4/profile instead?**  I've tried the following variations on the redirect_to statement to no effect, they all result in the same incorrect url:

```
redirect_to( user_profile_path(@user), ... )
redirect_to( user_profile_path(@user, @profile), ... )
redirect_to([@user, @profile], ... )
redirect_to( @profile, ... )
```

What's more, using 'user_profile_path(@user)' elsewhere produces the correct url.

Any ideas?  Oh, and I'm using Rails 3.0.0 and Ruby 1.9.2 if that helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After looking around, it appears that the form generating the update had an incorrect url.  If anyone is seeing this issue, it's because I had my form set up as:

```
form_for [@user, @profile] do |f| ...
```

This caused the form action to have the incorrect url (of the offending form above).  Instead, I used

```
form_for @profile, :url => user_profile_path(@user) do |f| ...
```

and everything seemed to work.

Comment: I'm having this problem too. The routing should be smart enough to know that it's dealing with @profile which is a singular and not put the id in the url. I hope there's a way to work around this because I'm dealing with polymorphic url's out of necessity as I don't know what class one of the parent objects is (in your case it I wouldn't know that @user is necessarily a User class).

Comment: This is a long stanting [bug in rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1769)

Answer (score 4):

You should redirect to user_profile_path(@user) since as your routes says it is:

```
/users/:user_id/profile(.:format)
```

If you look at it closely, then you will see, that there is only :user_id parameter needed, thou it is only @user in a path.

```
/users/:user_id/profile/:id(.:format)
```

It would be correct if you had resource**s** :profiles in your routes.rb, then as well you could use your path as in your example.

Comment: In rails if you do double redirect, then you will have it crying loud! ^^" Maybe you left there something else. What is your current controller code?

Answer (score 0):

`user_profile_path(@user)` should be correct. You're sure that one is returning `mydomain.com/users/4/profile.22`?

Comment: Yes, but just to double check I added a 'puts' statement in prior to the redirect and that printed the correct path ('/users/4/profile'), even though the very next line, the redirect with the exact same code sent me to the fore-mentioned incorrect url.

Comment: `tail -f` your log file. Maybe it is doing more than one redirect. Just a hunch!