# Rails Nested Singular Resource Routing Appending .ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following nested singular route:

```
resources :listings do
  resource :logo, only: [ :edit, :update ]
end
```

It generates 2 correct routes as expected:

```
edit_listing_logo GET /listings/:listing_id/logo/edit(.:format) logos#edit
listing_logo PUT /listings/:listing_id/logo(.:format) logos#update
```

Now when I redirect to edit_listing_logo_path

```
redirect_to edit_listing_logo_path( @listing, @logo )
```

or when I create an update form

```
<%= form_for [ @listing, @logo ] do |f| %>
```

the resulting link has always singular resource ID attached at the end like this

```
/listings/2/logo.1
```

I'm not using respond formats in this app yet so it's working fine. But this link generation seems strange and I expect it to cause problems if used with various respond formats.

Note, that this was also discussed here [Rails Nested Singular Resource Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765266/rails-nested-singular-resource-routing) but I'm not using 'show' path at all.

Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: 'edit' and 'show' path work the same way so you've got everything you need in the question you mentioned !

Comment: why would they work the same way?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's just for the first part of your answer : you can use `redirect_to edit_listing_logo_path(@listing)` because if you check this line : `edit_listing_logo GET /listings/:listing_id/logo/edit(.:format) logos#edit`, you can see that :logo_id is not required in the route. For the second part, you can add a show path and use @Bryan Marble answer.

Comment: Okay.. in redirects, this works `edit_listing_logo_path( @listing )` and make sense since we don't need ID of the logo.

Comment: But I had to change the form helper code to `form_for @logo, url: listing_logo_path( @listing ), method: :put`. This generates correct /listings/2/logo PUT action. IMO `form_for [ @listing, @logo ] do |f|` should generate same link as well so I think it's a bug. Removing @listing or @logo doesn't help in this case because it tries to generate not-nested route in both cases.

Comment: @MartinSojka Any update on this, I agree form_for [ listing, logo ] do |f| should work

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get the answer you need either by using the verbose path method `edit_listing_logo_path(@listing)` (as mentioned by @Martin Sojka) or  by using a symbol instead of the object itself.

So instead of using the normal form:

```
form_for [ @listing, @logo ]
```

you can dispose of the object specificity (and the trailing ID) by writing:

```
form_for [@listing :logo]
```

and if you want to call another action on the controller you can prefix it in the array:

```
form_for [:edit, @listing :logo]
```

Hope it works for you - it seemed to solve my issues.

Comment: Yes it's using the id of the 2nd object and appending it as the format of the request URL. The object id is unnecessary as it is a singular resource.

Comment: I think you're missing a `,` in your 2nd & 3rd examples. Also, it doesn't seem to work with or without the comma in Rails 5.